# Initialize Property of array or strings from custom class

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, initialization

I have tried a number of different things but cant seem to find the right syntax to initialize this array of strings.

I have it in a custom class

```
Public Class datahere

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property parameters() As String
    Public Property elem As XElement

End Class
```

and I declare it like so

```
Dim xdata(newdata.Count) As datahere
```

But not sure how to go about using it.
I use the other variables like so

```
xdata(3).Name = "TEST"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this ..

First change like this

```
Public Property parameters As List(Of String)
```

And create array class

```
Dim ListDH as List(Of DataHere)

Dim par as New Parameter
par.Add("Any value")

Dim DH as New DataHere

DH.Name = "Test"
DH.Parameter = par
DH.Property = ....

ListDH.Add(DH)
```

So you can access if by

```
ListDH(0).Name          '-----> to get Name of first array ("TEST")

ListDH(0).Parameter(0)  '-----> to get First array of Parameter from the list ("Any value")
```

Comment: Hey, but what about the array of strings? That is the thing I am having trouble with and would run in to the same problem with the list

Comment: How is this the selected answer when it doesn't answer the question? The question asks how to declare an array of strings, and this answer says how to create a list(of string).

Answer (score 1):

Although I would recommend using a List(of String) for your Parameters Property, if you insist on using arrays you can do the following.

First change the parameters property to the following:

```
Public Property parameters As String()
```

Keep in mind that xdata(3).parameters(0) will be nothing.  To change that you would specify the number of items in the array like so:

```
ReDim xdata(3).parameters(0)
'Give it a value
xdata(3).parameters(0) = "Test 1"
```

If you want to add additional items you have to redefine the array.  To prevent losing your existing data use the Preserve Keyword:

```
ReDim Preserve xdata(3).parameters(1)
'Give the second item in the array a value
xdata(3).parameters(1) = "Test 2"
```

To get your values is pretty straight forward:

```
Dim strSecondParameters As Strign = xdata(3).parameters(1)
```